# iOS 3.1.2: UIImageViews not respecting frame size

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview

I have a universal iOS application, and all of my images are sized for the iPad. To size them correctly on the iPhone, I use the UIImageView Frame property. However, I just tested out my app on an iPhone 1 running iOS 3.1.2, and all of the images are showing up full size! They show up correctly on every device running iOS 4 that I have tested on. Does anyone know why this is or how to fix it? I don't want to just make iPhone-sized versions of all my images, because I zoom in and out of images in my app by changing their frame size.

Thanks! 
Anita

Answer (score 1):

You can scale the image with half of the image size and scale to fill, will work which i do follow.

```
UIImage* originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"demo.jpg"];
originalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage] scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

and wherever you are setting this image to any control lets say UIView

```
UIView *demoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height)];
```

Comment: I think it would be easiest to change the autoresizing field in the xib, but I think your code is the most effecient since I believe your code will result in a lower memory footprint.  I think changing the autoresizingMask on the imageView effects how the image renders, but the image has all the data, whereas your code saves space by resizing the image itself.

Comment: @Anita any time and any way i saw your smart cookies studio, good stuff. :)

Comment: Ya, I'm a newsletter subscribee now.  :)  Good luck Anita.

Comment: Thank you to both of you for the help! Turns out, the elements that were showing up incorrectly were UIButtons, not UIImageViews (I hadn't noticed because both have the same properties). I was setting the image for the UIButton using the Image property, and it was not respecting the Frame size. When I tried settings the image using the BackgroundImage property instead of the Image property, it worked! What a strange bug, glad it was fixed in iOS 4!

Comment: I'm so glad glad you like the site, and thanks for subscribing!:) I am planning to submit to the app store early next week, so you should be getting an e-mail about the release soon, I hope!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a xib with interface builder, make sure you have set the autosizing for the UIImageView.

If you create the UIImageViews in code, you will want something like:

```
        myImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Answer (score 0):

try remove

```
sizeToFit
```

property.  I've the same issue and removing sizeToFit was solved.